# Return NULL when distinct values else return value

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Below is an example of the type of data I get (collected by different users):

| name | surname |
| --- | --- |
| Moe | Momo |
| Moe | Momo |
| Jack | JAJA |
| Jack | Jacky |

I would like to find when two users have collected different surnames for the same name.

The output I'm trying to get is:

| name | surname |
| --- | --- |
| Moe | Momo |
| Jack | NULL |

I would see the surname if all users have collected the same, and NULL if there are differences.

I tried searching the internet but I'm not able to describe what I'm searching properly.

I tried a request using CASE, but with no success.

Comment: What would you consider the right output to be if one of the surname values in the original table is NULL?

Comment: @PaulWhite it should be NULL as different values would be present for the same name thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved using `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`.  Group the results by `name`.  Count distinct last names per first name.  If the count differs from 1, show the last name as a null, otherwise show the actual last name e.g. using `MAX`, like this:

```
SELECT
  name
, surname = CASE COUNT(DISTINCT surname) WHEN 1 THEN MAX(surname) END
FROM
  dbo.People
GROUP BY
  name
;
```

You have to apply an aggregate function to `surname` because the grouping is by `name` only.  Since you only show it when the distinct count is 1, it should not matter much which instance you pick, since they are all the same.  `MIN` would work as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can just group by `first_name`, and compare the `MIN` with the `MAX` and see if they are the same.

```sql
SELECT
  n.first_name,
  CASE WHEN MIN(n.last_name) = MAX(n.last_name) THEN MIN(n.last_name) END AS last_name
FROM #names n
GROUP BY
  n.first_name;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b09a15797dd2737a51fba509389b780c)

Comment: Functionally equivalent to checking `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`, but standard SQL and will probably perform much better!

Comment: Indeed, this does not require a sort over `first_name, last_name` only `first_name`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be using the [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
with cte as 
( select n.*, 
         count(*) over (partition by first_name, last_name) as cnt
from #names n
) select distinct first_name, 
         case when cnt > 1 then last_name else NULL end as last_name
  from cte ;
```

The `partition by first_name, last_name` part will count for the first_name/last_name combined. If the cnt > 1 then same user have same first and last name.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e7176662c85c0d86c0157b2a75b66f7)

*Note*. If in your dataset you have same user with twice same first_name and last_name and once with differ first_name and last_name for the differ part it will return null like below example:

```
Moe  | Momo
Moe  | Momo
Jack | JAJA
Jack | Jacky
Jack | Jacky
```

The result would be :

```
first_name  last_name
 Jack        null
 Jack        Jacky
 Moe         Momo
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f604e29be13490818f5e1875e8719eb

Answer (score 2):

There are more than a few ways to do this, but to move forward with your `CASE` statement approach, you just need to include some aggregates, similar to the following:

```
SELECT first_name, CASE WHEN repeats > 1 THEN last_name ELSE NULL END as last_name
FROM
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) as repeats
    FROM #names
    GROUP BY first_name, last_name
) t
GROUP BY first_name, CASE WHEN repeats > 1 THEN last_name ELSE NULL END
```

Here's the full [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c9349fa20b4b7aa6a1be2e612fbb94b) for reference

There are probably more efficient approaches out there as well, but this should at least get you the limited results you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a modification of [Andriy's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/313832/1192). It considers a NULL in the second column to be distinct:

```
CREATE TABLE #names
(
    first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(255) NULL
);

INSERT #names
    (first_name, last_name)
VALUES
    ('Moe', 'Momo'),
    ('Moe', 'Momo'),
    ('Jack', 'JAJA'),
    ('Jack', 'Jacky'),
    ('Paul', 'White'),
    ('Paul', NULL);

SELECT 
    N.first_name, 
    last_name =
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT N.last_name) = 1      -- one non-null value
                AND COUNT_BIG(*) = COUNT_BIG(N.last_name) -- no nulls
            THEN MAX(N.last_name)
            ELSE NULL
        END
FROM #names AS N
GROUP BY N.first_name;
```

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| Jack | NULL |
| Moe | Momo |
| Paul | NULL |

[*db<>fiddle* online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3961cf8bec9bb144dc4d19cf11a96b0f)